# What is the connector for bare wires that locks the wire with an orange button?

Tags: connector, wire-terminals

I've seen this type of connector on garage door openers and other consumer equipment. It has holes for the stripped wire end, and an orange button that can be pressed with a screwdriver to open the contacts in the hole. The wire is inserted, and when the pressure on the orange tab is released, the contacts in the hole close to hold the wire securely.

What is the name / manufacturer / brand of this type of connector?

[image: example]

Comment: That exact kind and physical format? No idea. But descriptively they are called spring-clamp connectors.

Comment: Aka "[cage clamp terminal block](https://www.google.com/search?q=cage+clamp+terminal+block&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS906US906&oq=cage+clamp&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l9.2927j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)". Phoenix Contact makes a ton of them along with other well-known manufacturers like Wago, etc. Even more lesser-known  companies shamelessly copy their well-known counterparts.